# Phonegap and asp.net webapi user authentication

Tags: asp.net, cordova, asp.net-web-api

I'm currently busy with a asp.net webapi project with a phonegap client, having issues getting started with how the user will be authenticated using JavaScript in my phonegap project?

I already have simplemembership setup as I have a web frontend that uses it, my main concern is how do I get started authenticating users in my phonegap providing a username and password, and how I can integrate this with my existing simplemembership setup in my mvc project, I've searched Google a lot for this but couldn't find a specific implementation/example using phonegap and webapi. I'm just looking to get started in the right direction.

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22607996/secure-web-api-called-by-phonegap-application) I have replied here for the same question and waiting on thoughts from other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you enable HTTP Basic auth and you have a username and password field you can do the authentication like that

```js
var username = $("#username").val();
var password = $("#password").val();
 
$.ajax({
  url: "url",
  type: "GET",
  beforeSend: function (xhr) {
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic "+$.base64.encode(username + ":" + password););
  },
  success: ajaxSuccessHandler,
  error: ajaxErrHandler
});
```